# An ordinal that is finite or infite?

Tags: set-theory

Let $\beta $ be an ordinal such that for all $\gamma $   $2^{\aleph_{\gamma}}$ =
$\aleph_{\gamma + \beta}$. Does $\beta $ have to be infinity?. Under the continuum hypothesis, it is true, let 0= $\gamma $ and then we have an absurdity. But in ZFC, without CH, what happens? I tried to see that for if $\gamma $ is a natural number, then we have that $\aleph_{\gamma + \beta}$ = $\aleph_{\beta}$ and then i have to use cofinality, but i don´t know the cofinality of $2^{\aleph_{\gamma}}$ with $\gamma $ natural.

Answer (score 3):

The generalized continuum hypothesis (GCH) states that for all $\gamma$:
$$2^{\aleph_{\gamma}}=\aleph_{\gamma+1}.$$
Thus $\beta$ clearly need not be infinite!

Since you can construct a model of ZFC where $2^{\aleph_{0}}=\aleph_{1}$ but $2^{\aleph_{1}}=\aleph_{3}$, it can also be the case that such a $\beta$ need not exist.

The value of $\beta$ cannot be $\omega$, since that would imply that $\mathfrak{c}=\aleph_{\omega}$, which is absurd since the two sides of this equation have different cofinalities.

The same issue prevents $\beta$ from being any other infinite ordinal: if $$\forall \gamma \, \Big(2^{\aleph_{\gamma}}=\aleph_{\gamma+\beta}\Big)$$ for some infinite $\beta$, then put $\gamma=\beta$: the RHS has cofinality at most $\beta$, but the LHS has cofinality strictly greater than $\beta$.

I don't know enough set theory to say for sure that one can construct models where your equation holds for any finite $\beta>1$ , but it sounds reasonable to me.

Comment: Your argument does not quite work as written, because $\beta$ may be a successor ordinal, in which case the right hand side is regular, and has cofinality greater than $\beta$.  Anyway, we can fix this and we have that if the equation holds for all $\gamma$, then $\beta$ is indeed finite, and it has been shown consistent (from large cardinals) that any finite $\beta\ge1$ is possible. If $\beta>1$, the use of large cardinals is needed.

Comment: Thanks for that comment!  My set theory was a while ago and anyway was not the most shining moment of my graduate school career.  It's good to have it looked over by someone more knowledgeable.

Answer (score 2):

The Generalized Continuum Hypothesis states exactly that $\beta=1$ has the property you're defining. And it is known to be independent of ZFC, so ZFC certainly cannot prove that finite $\beta$s can't work.

(The Continuum Hypothesis is the claim $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$, or in other words just your equation with $\beta=1$ and $\gamma=0$ -- so the "absurdity" you speak of must be based on a misunderstanding somehow).